# wrapAll() for each multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some tabs each one with video player, some of them with chapters and some of them with a playlist.

As I'm not able to change the html structure I use this bit of code to get everything how I need it.

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

//Chapters
    
    var chapters = document.querySelectorAll('.chapters');
          
        $(chapters).each(function(){
      
        $("<div class='chapter-title'></div>" ).insertBefore(this);
        });
    
                       
        $('.tab1 .chapter-title, .tab1 .chapters').wrapAll('<div class="chapter_wrapper" />');
                    
        $('.tab2 .chapter-title,.tab2 .chapters').wrapAll('<div class="chapter_wrapper" />');
    
//Playlists
    
    var playlists = document.querySelectorAll('.playlist');
    
    $(playlists).each(function(){
      
            $("<div class='playlist-title'></div>").insertBefore(this);
        });
                     
    $('.tab2 .playlist-title, .tab2 .playlist').wrapAll('<div class="playlist_wrapper" />');
                     
});
    
</script>
```

As the amount of tabs, players etc. will increase in future, I want to ask if there's a way to use the `wrapAll()` method for each multiple selections that I don#t have to use the `.tab1, .tab2, .tab3` etc. selectors everytime.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What’s the original structure and what’s the structure you want?

Comment: Your `.tab1` / `.tab2` elements *should* also have a generic/common class, eg just `tab` (so would be `class='tab tab1`).   So you could use `$('.tab .chapter-title')` to pick them all up.   Alternatively, if your chapters are *only* within tabs, then you don't need the tab1/tab2 part at all: `$(".chapter-title,.chapters")` would select the same elements.